# Why are file systems so much slower then a database?

Tags: linux, database, file, filesystems, tableofcontents

I have a lot of files on my computer (who doesn't).
It is split between harddrives.

I realized a long time ago, that find takes a whole lot of time scanning the whole harddisk. Minutes, for all drives i might take over an hour,

That is why I got used to running `du -ba / >> ~/du."$*(date +%F)"` on a regular base. Then I would just `grep 'WHATEVER' ~/du | sed 's#^ \+[0-9]\+ ##' | xargs -d\\n command`

I understand why that is faster than `find`.

Now I set up a mysql, that has a complete, refreshable index of all files. directories are a simple tree with just a foreign key to the parent row. (or however you call a foreign key that references NOT to a foreign table but to it's own primary of a different row).

Although It is as complex, it is still much faster than using the Filesystems.

Why is that? Am I missing some tools that could search the TOC faster than the normal posix calls to the kernel?

How long should It take to print all files of a harddrive to stdout, whithout a DB or textfile cache?